# is there a way to print a specific amount of characters from multiple lists? (Word generator)

Tags: python

new to coding here and am starting out by attempting to create a simple phrase generator.
(I apologize if my questions aren't formatted properly, but I will try my best.)

I have created a small phrase generator, but I am trying to only get the phrases that are less than 35 characters. I also am trying not to create cut off sentences. So that brings me to my question, is it possible to retrieve only the sentences/phrases that are 35 characters and less from a set of different lists?

here is my code

````
import csv
from random import randint
other = ["leave","place","set","rest","prop on","lean","lay","stow","sit","set"]
names=["front","back"]
verbs=["door,", "side,","porch,","steps","stairs","stairway","staircase","entry","stoop"]
nouns=["Thanks a ton", "Thanks a million", "forever indebted", "please thanks","super great","appreciated",
       "thank you","deep gratitude","means the world","TYSM","Congrats Champ","Keep on going","Never quit","Believe 4ever"
       ,"you did it","always believe","love persists","frenz forever","pat on back","kudos bro","mad thanks","best ever","gift for her",
       "gift for cousin","u deserve it","keep it real","love u girl","u make my wrld","thankful","best wishes","stay warm","stay cool","2 my bestie",]```


while True:
    phrase_amount = input("How many phrases would you like to create?")


    for i in range(int(phrase_amount)):
        
        print((other[randint(0,len(other)-1)]+" "+names[randint(0,len(names)-1)]+" "+verbs[randint(0,len(verbs)-1)]+" "+nouns[randint(0,len(nouns)-1)]))
````

Secondly, I am doing something wrong when writing to csv. The output is printing in multiple rows and columns, and I am unsure what's going on here. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
csvname = f"{phrase_amount}"
with open (f'PhrasesbyTrill{csvname}.csv','w', newline='') as file:
    myfile = csv.writer(file)
    myfile.writerow(["Phrases"])

    for i in range(int(phrase_amount)):
        
        myfile.writerow((other[randint(0,len(other)-1)]+" "+names[randint(0,len(names)-1)]+" "+verbs[randint(0,len(verbs)-1)]+" "+nouns[randint(0,len(nouns)-1)]))
```

Comment: Hello and welcome! I would suggest breaking your question into two different posts. It’s best to include one question per post

Answer (score 0):

Just save the phrase on a variable, check the length and print it. Something like:

```
    for i in range(int(phrase_amount)):
        
        phrase = (other[randint(0,len(other)-1)]+" "+names[randint(0,len(names)-1)]+" "+verbs[randint(0,len(verbs)-1)]+" "+nouns[randint(0,len(nouns)-1)])
        if len(phrase)>35:
            print(phrase)
```

Comment: Will this only print sentences that are greater than 35 characters?

Comment: Yes, but also counting spaces. So, if you have a phrase "How are you?" this is 12 characters, not 10. But I suggest you try it out :), that's the best way to certify that what im saying is true.

Comment: For the csv question, I suggest you open another question.

Comment: ok, for some reason i am still having an issue when trying your suggestion! I really appreciate the help! But when i use <35 which i want less than 35 character sentences, The program doesnt print anything, it just restarts the loop?

Comment: that means no phrase is smaller than 35 characthers. Add a print(len(phrase)) before the if and you will see.

Comment: you rock that works!

Comment: Mark the answer as valid if it helped you so it can help other people ;)

Comment: so if i input 10 when it ask how many phrases i want. Ill get something like 
How many phrases would you like to create?12
28
lean back steps keep it real
31
30

Is there a way to get the program to print 10 actual phrases <35 characters?

Comment: Still not very clear :D 
So you tell the program you want 10 phrases. What does the program need to do after?

Comment: its printing some numbers and phrases, so if i enter 10 when it asks for how many phrases i want, ill get maybe 4 and the rest are the lengths that are too long. is there a way to get the 10 phrases that are under 25 characters?

Comment: the numbers you get is because of the print(len(phrase)) you added before. Just get rid of it. Problem here is that the random generator onPC is not really random, it will repeat after some time. So the code I suggested together with yours should do what you ask.

Comment: I am also getting lengths that print that are like 28. (They ARE less than 35, but not printing?